# ORA00907: Missing Right Parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

When I run this query:

```
select prnt_c_fam_id as PRNT_C_FAM_ID3, min(ptel_d_redet_due) as Date_DUE
  from ptel t
 where ptel_d_redet_due > (select max(rest_d)
                             from   rest 
                            where  prnt_c_fam_id = t.prnt_c_fam_id
                              and rest_c in ('RS'))
group by prnt_c_fam_id 
order by prnt_c_fam_id
```

The query returns successfully. When I add parenthesis around it:

```
(select prnt_c_fam_id as PRNT_C_FAM_ID3, min(ptel_d_redet_due) as Date_DUE
   from ptel t
  where ptel_d_redet_due > (select max(rest_d)
                             from   rest 
                            where  prnt_c_fam_id = t.prnt_c_fam_id
                              and rest_c in ('RS'))
 group by prnt_c_fam_id 
 order by prnt_c_fam_id)
```

I get the ORA00907: Missing Right Paranthesis error. Anybody know why? (Note: this query needs the parenthesis because it becomes a subquery in the from clause of a larger query. The other subqueries work with and without the parenthesis while running separately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using it as a subquery remove the order by clause.Subquery should look like below.

```
      (
       select prnt_c_fam_id as PRNT_C_FAM_ID3, min(ptel_d_redet_due) as Date_DUE
       from ptel t
       where ptel_d_redet_due > (select max(rest_d)
       from   rest 
       where  prnt_c_fam_id = t.prnt_c_fam_id
       and rest_c in ('RS'))
       group by prnt_c_fam_id 
      )
```

Comment: Thanks VJ. That solved the problem but introduced another issue in the query we now have to figure out.